# Displaying estimated computational time when running tools in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geoprocessing

I'm almost positive I have set up models to display the estimated runtime/computational time for the models/tools in the past, but I can't seem remember how to turn on this option. I've looked around the web to no avail and would like to determine if this is even possible.

If it is not possible to just turn on the option is there python code I can use to get this information?

Comment: This is my mistake for not being clear enough with my question. How do I get the runtime/computational time to display in the tool dialog box?

Comment: Showing progress can be added as Aaron mentioned. Getting estimated time? You mean running the Clip tool on some arbitrary datasets and getting the message "this will take about 5 min"? Seriously doubt there have ever been such an option. There are some tools for ArcGIS Server cache creation which can give you a hint, but nothing like this with the core GIS processing tools. Would be useful yet quite hard to implement in practice (should collect statistics on previous runs on your machine to make a prediction).

Comment: Were you running standard tools from Esri or custom script tools? If the latter, someone may have scripted time estimates.

Comment: I can't think of a tool that reports when it thinks it'll be done. But I dont know all 900+ tools. I can say the vast majority of core/analysis type tools do NOT report this information. Tools almost always report % complete. Maybe the caching tools report how much time is left?

Comment: I cannot *ever* remember getting an ETA (ETC) for a tool, not even in workstation 3.1, certainly not in 8.3, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3.1 - I've worked with all of them and have never (to my recollection) been given an estimated time for the tool to complete... even if I did I would ignore it (Microsoft Minutes!). The best you're going to get is an indication of how far the tool is through its task. If you want to access this use arcpy.SetProgressor http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000003z000000 (this should work foreground and background)

Comment: In theory, you could write your own tools that implement IFeatureProgress in such a way to report this information, but doing so is fraught with difficulty (I've spent several years of my life staring at a Windows installer reporting "1 second remaining").  Percent complete is a much safer progress to report (if it's even known, of course).

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson it is quite possible that I have made this up in my head. I will do further research in the future, I've been busy with deadlines.

Comment: @Vince I agree that 1 second remaming can often be frustrating, but its also frustrating when you don't seen the progress bar move at all. This may be due to the fact that the process that is running will likely take many hours or multiple days. This is the information that I would like to determine.

Comment: But you **can't** determine how long that last little bit will take if the update interval doesn't support it.  I write my tools to report progress at 5,10,20,40... percent *and* at 1,5,15,30... minute intervals, so that if progress *is* being made, you'll know within 15 minutes.  I'll also add a "stop.now" file existence test in the main loop, so that graceful shutdown can be accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

By default, newer versions of ArcGIS run tools in the background. When models are running in the background, there is not a nifty progress bar.  In order to get the progress bar back, you need to disable background geoprocessing via:

> Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options > Background Processing >
>   Deselect check box

Of course this may effect processing performance, so be aware of that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're statement as-is, isn't entirely correct. Since 10 (or was it 10.1?) background processing has been the default inside ArcMap/Catalog. At 10.2.1 a separate, downloadable installation of 64bit Background was made available and can be optionally installed. My point is: 32 or 64, it doesn't matter. Background processing is just that when it comes to interaction within the app. Either you're using it or not, regardless if you've downloaded 64bit.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @KHibma, I have removed reference to 64-bit processing.

Comment: @Aaron The screen grabs are informative, but still only tell you how long a process has run. I'm looking for a way to determine how long a process may take. I'm pretty sure I've seen this pop up as warnings in the dialog box when done before.

Answer (score 2):

Just open the Results window (Geoprocessing menu - Results) and expand your current session. The time of execution is available under the Messages.

Comment: +1 This is a handy tip.  Although, be advised that this method gives the start and end time only after the tool has run, with no indication of ongoing progress.

Comment: Yes what @Aaron said. I have used this to get information after the fact, but it doesn't help me understand how long a currently running process may take.